# are there any tablet emulators to check my website?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, compatibility, mobile-website

I am creating a web application.  I am creating it in MVC4.  I just want to check to see what the pages look like in different tablets. so wondering if there are any tablet emulators for windows?

Anyone know any that they can recommend?  Would be great if they can access localhost

Thanks

Comment: http://www.browserstack.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to [this Web Site](http://responsivetest.net/) and [this web Site](http://www.studiopress.com/responsive/). They support `localhost:port` too. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/455627/MVC4-Mobile-Friendly-Web-Applications) is useful For Building successful mobile/tablet web applications in MVC4.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

In Chapter 4 of Programming the Mobile Web Max Firtman has made an extensive description and installation guideline for creating a desktop mobile testing environment. And in Chapter 13, he has also reviewed other solutions for mobile testing, including four device remote lab solutions.

Max Firtman has mixed all the information to create an ultimate guide to 37 download resources for hundreds of emulators and simulators.

[Mobile Emulators & Simulators: The Ultimate Guide](http://www.mobilexweb.com/emulators)

The list has also some tablet emulators.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the Opera emular

[Opera Mobile Classic Emulator](http://www.opera.com/developer/mobile-emulator)